# How to tell when WMP is done playing a video?

Tags: vb.net, windows-media-player, wmp

**BACKGROUND:**

I have a project where I am using a touchscreen for what video to play on the TV next to it. Both are connected to the same computer and the a VB app runs that then opens a video in window media player on the TV. We are opening video files by Process.start and have a string with the files location.

**ISSUE:**

I need to play a video twice when selected and then go back to a main video after playing the initial video twice. How can I determine when the video has finished playing? Videos are all the same file type but simply using the file size to try to determine length does not work. Two videos of the same length have a noticeable difference in file size.

So either I need to know what the length of the video is or when the video is finished.

Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub Button17_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button17.Click, Button18.Click, Button19.Click, Button20.Click, Button21.Click, Button22.Click, Button23.Click, Button24.Click, Button25.Click, Button26.Click, Button27.Click, Button28.Click, Button29.Click, Button30.Click, Button31.Click, Button32.Click
    Dim bNum As Integer
    Dim temp As String
    Try
        MR = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("S:\A - All Other Sales Folders\Robots - All Files\YouTube Videos\Videos without Intro's\Material Removal")
        temp = Strings.Mid(sender.Name, 7)
        bNum = CInt(temp)
        Process.Start(MR(bNum - 17))
        wait(600) 'just have it go for 10 minutes unless they want to change videos, not the best solution here for a few reasons
        Process.Start("S:\A - All Other Sales Folders\Robots - All Files\YouTube Videos\Videos without Intro's\RobotClips_KUKA Presentation_05-13-09.wmv") 'video to play on loop
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you post the section of code where you're loading them?  When I wrote similar code, I made use of the [PlayStateChange Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562460(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Process.Start("S:\A - All Other Sales Folders\Robots - All Files\YouTube Videos\Videos without Intro's\RobotClips_KUKA Presentation_05-13-09.wmv")

We are not actually playing the video within a form just calling the file.

Comment: If you store the process in a variable you can do `Process.WaitForExit()` although not sure when this fires on a media player. You can also never be sure that it will play via WMP on a client's machine.